# Is this undocumented functionality officially suported by the semtech sx1276?

Tags: interface, lora, documentation, sx1276

Often after transmitting a message on the sx1276 operating in LoRa mode, the sx1276 is put in receive mode to allow receiving a message. Empirically, I have found that the opreg can be written to receive continuous mode while the sx1276 is still transmitting. The opreg will not read back as in receive continuous mode until the sx1276 is finished transmitting.

From my perspective this is a great feature that doesn't seem to be documented on the datasheet. The datasheet indicates that you need to wait for the transmission to complete and the sx1276 to be in standby mode before the opreg can be written to receive continuous mode.

Has anyone seen any official documentation from semtech saying this great feature is supported?

Comment: You could always email Semtech.

Comment: Semtech doesn't seem to allow entry of a support request from gmail or oulook email accounts.

Comment: Seems like a great find! It's not surprising to work like that. I assume you tested that the TX packet goes out in its entirety before the switch happens? The only real other question is how early in the transmission one can trigger the switch to RX...

Comment: It would be a great find if Semtech would say that they support this feature.  Empirically, I have found that after I issue

Comment: sorry about the broken comment

Comment: It would be a great find if Semtech would say that they support this feature.  Empirically, I have found that after  the command "writeRegister(REG_OP_MODE, MODE_LONG_RANGE_MODE | MODE_TX);" is issued,  issuing the command "writeRegister(REG_OP_MODE, MODE_LONG_RANGE_MODE | MODE_RX_CONTINUOUS);" within 100 microseconds or so works.  The transmission completes and a response to the transmission is received. It seems to work the same way as if the read command was issued after the transmission completed.